# Android Backup Extract Error in CMD

Tags: java, android, cmd, backup

im a totally newbie in Java but I need to get some Pictures out of my old Galaxy S3 Backup to save my relationship... 
I use WIN 7 64 bit

So I dowloaded http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/ and used this in CMD with admin rights:

java -jar "E:\android-backup-extractor-20130526-bin\abe.jar" unpack "E:\HandyBackup\backup.ab" "E:\entpackt\backup.tar"

to extract the backup. But everytime I get the Error:

```
Strong AES encryption disabled

Magic: ANDROID BACKUP
Version: 1
Compressed: 1
Algorithm: AES-256
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLo
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Back
p encrypted but password not specified
        at org.nick.abe.AndroidBackup.extractAsTar(AndroidBackup.java:320)
        at org.nick.abe.Main.main(Main.java:58)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Backup encrypted but password no
 specified
        at org.nick.abe.AndroidBackup.extractAsTar(AndroidBackup.java:220)
        ... 6 more
```

Im not sure if you have all information that you need to help me out if not just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error only when the size of the backup file was 0 kb, just check to make sure that this is not your case